# coding issues Unknown error

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

```
public void AddCustomers(string CName, string Cadd, string CContact, string CCity, string CRegion, string CCountry)
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=SAAD;database=Inventory_management;integrated security=true");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddCustomers", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CName", CName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cadd", Cadd);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CContact", CContact);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CCity", CCity);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CRegion", CRegion);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CCountry", CCountry);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
}
```

This is my class code, and this is my aspx.cs code

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            cc.AddCustomers(CustomerName.Text, Address.Text, ContactNo.Text, City.Text, Region.Text, Country.Text);
            GridView1.DataSource = cc.getcustomers();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

I get this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CustomerID', table 'Inventory_management.dbo.Customers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

What should I do now? Anyone help

Comment: *What should I do now?* well, **read** the error message, and then do as it says - insert a value for `CustomerID` into that table!

Comment: i did but it dosent work

Comment: now its giving this error
Error converting data type nvarchar to int.

Comment: You need to set that column to type if INT ( not var char ) - Then you should be able to add the auto INC - ( also make sure that it it 'UNSIGNED INT' - In addition this should be primary key of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the customerID column set to 'auto increment' - If not, then this is probably the reason for your issue...

Comment: it dosent give me any option of increment

Answer (score 0):

-- Your table should be created something like this --

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
    (
    CustomerID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Cadd varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CContact varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CCity varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CRegion varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CCountry varchar(255) NOT NULL
    )
```